# Android Virtual Device (AVD) Manager

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

To create an AVD for Target Android 3.0 API 11, what device and skin I should choose?
The available choices being Nexus 7, Nexus 5, Nexus 4, Nexus 10, Galaxy Nexus, Nexus S, Nexus One.

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to choose target API when creating virtual device. See 'Target' option on the screenshot below. This dialog will appear after you click 'New...' button in the 'Android Virtual Devices' tab of AVD Manager.

[image: AVD creation dialog]

Comment: @AnjaliR, why do you think it's not helpful?